# Merge without doing update first?

Tags: mercurial

Say you have two branches *Stable* and *Unstable*. Let's assume I'm working in *Unstable* and when I'm done I commit my work and want to merge the new changes into *Stable*.

Do I have to update to *Stable* before the merge or is it possible to merge the changes to *Stable* while still having my working copy mirror head of *Unstable*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To merge `Unstable` into `Stable`, you must first update to `Stable`.

Merges are directional.  The direction of the merge is controlled by the revision of your working copy.

From the [`hg merge` help text](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/merge):

> merge working directory with another
>   revision
>
> The current working directory is
>   updated with all changes made in the
>   requested revision since the last
>   common predecessor revision.

Comment: I'm aware that the merges are directional, but I was hoping there was any way to do the merge (in the correct direction) without doing the update first. The team I belong to is spread out over the world and the developer repositories are all located on the same server and not on a local computer. Doing the update sometimes takes a couple of minutes depending on network load.

Comment: @MdaG: Unfortunately, there are no options for `hg merge` to do what you want.  As far as I know, you *must* update first.

Comment: One option is to just keep two clones around, one updated to 'stable' and one to 'unable'.  So long as they're push/pull equivalent (hg incoming and hg outgoing say they both have the same changesets) you can do the merge on the one that's always updated to stable, and then just push it to the other.